# In Tizen, Orientation sensor value is always -1

Tags: sensors, tizen

By using Sensor API, I want to get the Orientation sensor values. 
(sensor.h)

I followed tutorial (URL: https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/native-application/system/sensor?langredirect=1#retrieve), wrote same code except selecting Orientation sensor.

Lastly, when I called 'seonsor_listener_read_data()' function, I got just '-1'

But I knew the azimuth range is 0 <= and <= 360. I think it's weird.

Before I googled, somebody said that it might be broken sensor. But I'm not sure.

Any guys know how to solve it? or know reasons?

Comment: May I know on which device you are trying¿

Comment: Hello I tried by Galaxy S2 @srkushwaha

Comment: Galaxy S2 is android phone. Are you talking about Gear S2? You can post your query here you might get your answer very soon http://developer.samsung.com/forum/en

Comment: Not about android or gear s2. actually I knew galaxy s2 also can be installed tizen.. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about galaxy s2 with tizen.

Comment: I solved it. The sensor needs time to measure. According to some guy's opinion, Orientation sensor rate varies between 100~ 170ms. So, with the delay time, I got correct values. Thank you @srkushwaha.

Answer (score 0):

The Gear S2 doesn't support the orientation sensor.